# Tranfer Contents inside a Rotated Polygon to Bitmap

Tags: c#, drawing, transform, picturebox, rectangles

I'm using C# WinForms.
The rotated polygon is drawn on a picturebox. The width and height of the rotated polygon is 101, 101. Now, I want to transfer the contents of rotated polygon to new bitmap of size 101,101

[image]

I tried to paint pixels of the rectangle using this code

```
 for (int h = 0; h < pictureBox1.Image.Height; h++)
        {
            for (int w = 0; w < pictureBox1.Image.Width; w++)
            {
                if (IsPointInPolygon(rotatedpolygon, new PointF(w, h)))
                {
                    g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, w, h, 1, 1); //paint pixel inside polygon
                }                   
            }
        }
```

The pixels are painted in the following manner:[image]

Now, how do I know which location on the rotated rectangle goes to which location in the new bitmap. That is how do i translate pixel co-ordinates of rotated rectangle to new bitmap.

or simply put, is it possible to map rows and columns from rotated rectangle to new bitmap as shown below?

[image]

Sorry, if the question is not clear.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you be more specific? Your example images show a polygon that appears to not be rectangular, never mind square. But your narrative seems to be saying you'll always be copying a square image. Please clarify. If all you want is a square, or even any rectangle, the basic approach is straightforward: create a new bitmap object the size you want, set up the transform to rotate and translate the source bitmap to the location you want, and then just draw the source bitmap. It gets a little more complex if you want to handle arbitrary polygons though.

Comment: sorry about the poor drawing skills, just assume them as squares/rectangle. Yes, I want to copy a square/rectangle to a new bitmap. I dont want to rotate the source image (bcoz I think it by doing so the source image will go through the interpolation process and there is chance of quality loss )

Comment: _"I dont want to rotate the source image"_ -- you don't have any choice about that, according to the way you've written your question. Computers only handle images with horizontal lines of pixels. If you want the image itself rotated, you have to rotate the bitmap. You had better clarify that aspect of your question, because it's important: it's the difference between teaching you how to use the transform feature of the `Graphics` class, and you simply not being able to accomplish your goal at all (because it's impossible).

Comment: Thank u Peter. I know the option of rotating the image. But instead of rotating the image, I want to try rotating the rectangle option and raised a question in SO to get the opinion from experts like you whether it is possible or not.....

Comment: _"I want to try rotating the rectangle option"_ -- I think you aren't really understanding what that means. At the end of the process, no matter how you do it, the source pixels will wind up in a different orientation, in the target bitmap. This is, like it or not, a type of transformation that will require some form of resampling, whether interpolation or simply reducing the size. Consider for example the simple case of a 45-degree rotation: along one edge of a square rotated 45 degrees, you have roughly 40% more pixels than that exact same edge oriented vertically or horizontally. ...

Comment: ... To map those pixels (diagonal in the source image) to a horizontal or vertical orientation, you will have to merge them. Similarly, a diagonal in the rotated square (horizontal or vertical in the source image) will wind up at a 45 degree angle in the target image, resulting in 40% more pixels there. Since there are more pixels in the output than in the input, you'll obviously have to interpolate between them to fill in the missing data. It doesn't matter what strategy you choose for finding the pixel values for the target image, it will always involve some method of resampling the bitmap.

Comment: got it. you are absolutely correct. I'll reply back in 5 minutes

Comment: Hello, Peter. I have added a new image to this post. please see the new image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you asking to do is not literally possible. Look at your diagram:

[image]

On the left side, you've drawn pixels that are themselves oriented diagonally. But, that's not how the pixels actually are oriented in the source bitmap. The source bitmap will have square pixels oriented horizontally and vertically.

So, let's just look at a little bit of your original image:

[image]

Consider those four pixels. You can see in your drawing that, considered horizontally and vertically, the top and bottom pixels overlap the left and right pixels. More specifically, if we overlay the actual pixel orientations of the source bitmap with your proposed locations of source pixels, we get something like this:

[image]

As you can see, when you try to get the value of the pixel that will eventually become the top-right pixel of the target image, you are asking for the top pixel in that group of four. But that top pixel is actually made up of two different pixels in the original source image!

The bottom line: if the visual image that you are trying to copy will be rotated during the course of copying, **there is no one-to-one correspondence between source and target pixels**.

To be sure, resampling algorithms that handle this sort of geometric projection do apply *concepts* similar to that which you're proposing. But they do so in a mathematically sound way, in which pixels are necessarily merged or interpolated as necessary to map the square, horizontally- and vertically-oriented pixels from the source, to the square, horizontally- and vertically-oriented pixels in the target.

The only way you could get literally what you're asking for — to map the pixels on a one-to-one basis without any change in the actual pixel values themselves — would be to have a display that itself rotated.

Now, all that said: I claim that you're trying to solve a problem that not only is not solvable, but also **is not worth solving**.

Display resolution is so high on modern computing devices, even on the phone that you probably have next to you or in your pocket, that the resampling that occurs when you rotate bitmap images is of no consequence to the human perception of the bitmap.

Just do it the normal way. It will work fine.

Comment: yes, there is no one-to-one correspondence between source and target pixels..that is the problem. my method is way too complex to implement, I was in an assumption that it can be done through some geometrical operation. Thank you for your time and clarifications.